# gphoto2 pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, libgphoto2

So I have been following this tutorial https://medium.com/nerdery/dslr-webcam-setup-for-linux-9b6d1b79ae22 and when I got to the point to actually take a photo with the camera I have no issues but when I get to try to capture with it I get 
`pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input`

The entire command is listed as follows:

```
$ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
ERROR: Movie capture error... Exiting.
Movie capture finished (0 frames)
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: The first two error mesages `ERROR: Movie capture error... Exiting.` and `Movie capture finished (0 frames)` indicates an issue with gphoto, not ffmpeg.

Comment: I checked for updates on gphoto, ffmpeg, and v4l2looopback-utils to see if anything was out of date but it seems nothing was. I double checked with gphoto as well to see if my camera is compatible and it is (Canon Rebel T1i). I've looked through other guides but none of them seem to have any troubleshooting steps. When I searched up the error message the errors were not related to gphoto either.

Comment: The lines I quoted are from gphoto e.g http://gphoto-software.10949.n7.nabble.com/Canon-50D-capture-movie-can-t-work-td16429.html

Comment: It looks like that post is in regards to recording a video instead of using the live view to use the camera as a webcam. I tried some of the suggestions but had no luck.

Comment: I only pointed out that those errors are emitted by gphoto, not ffmpeg.